# Column 'owners' in field is ambiguous

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im working with MySQL in java.

I'm trying to update the 'owners' field in one of the tables 'regApartmentsTable', 'gardApartmentsTable', 'penthousesTable', which is empty, and corresponds to specific apartmentNum and street, and replace it with the string 'newOwners'.

In order to do that I've wrote the following code:

```
st=connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE regApartmentsTable,gardApartmentsTable,penthousesTable SET owners=? " +
                "WHERE owners=? AND apartmentNum=? AND street=?");
st.setString(1, newOwners);
st.setString(2, "");
st.setInt(3, apartmentNum);
st.setString(4, streetName+" "+buildingNum);
```

I include the 3 tables since I need to look in all of them. (The required apartment, which has no owners, and matches the apartmentNum and street, cannot be in more than one table, if it helps anyone).

But, when I try to run this code, I get a "Column 'owners' in field is ambiguous" error.
Any ideas how else should I write the SQL command ?
thanks ahead!

Clarification (from older question):
Ok, I understood that the exception raises since 'owners' field is common in those three tables.
And yet, how do I solve the problem? I cannot add a prefix with the table's name (e.g. regApartmentsTable.owners) since I do not know in which table I'm going to find the required apartment... If I knew so, I wouldn't have searched in 3 tables.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Should I first search somehow in the 3 tables and then update the one which contains the appropriate apartment?

Comment: No, don't search-then-update. Just use three UPDATE statements, one table each.

Comment: Thought there's a shorter way to do that, in one line...

Comment: This is a case poor normalization. If there can be amore than one owner for any of the class of accommodation, then there should be an owners table that is linked by id to the table, and the properties should all be in the same table linked by an attribute indicating what type of accommodation they are. @MarkoTopolnik is right, though, multiple updates are needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot update 3 tables at a time using a query.It is possible through only procedure.

Comment: you mean by 'insert'?

Comment: In the stored procedure you'd still have three statements, so you are just shifting the weight around.